# ASP.NET: How to access repeater generated elements from javascript?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have a series of rows that are generated using an **asp:repeater**:

```
<asp:repeater ID="itemsRepeater" 
      OnItemDataBound="itemsRepeater_ItemDataBound" 
      runat="Server">
   <itemtemplate>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="linkView" runat="server"
               Text="<%# GetItemText((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" 
               NavigateUrl="<%# GetViewItemUrl((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="linkDelete" runat="server"
                Text="Delete"
                NavigateUrl="<%# GetDeleteUrl((ActionItem)Container.DataItem) %>" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

The repeater creates an HTML table, with each row containing a link to an item and (what is essentially) a "Delete" link. The above simplified example code generates HTML similar to:

```
<TR>
<TD>
   <A href="ViewItem.aspx?ItemGuid={19a149db-5675-4eee-835d-3d78372ca6f9}">
      AllisonAngle_SoccerGirl001.jpg
   </A>
</TD>
<TD>
   <A href="DeleteItem.aspx?ItemGuid={19a149db-5675-4eee-835d-3d78372ca6f9}">Delete</A>
</TD>
</TR>
```

Now that all works, but i want to convert the "Delete" to client side. i want to be able click the link and it will, on the client javascript:

- prompt an alert "Are you sure..."
- have javascript issue server-hit to actually delete the item they want
- remove the item from the client DOM tree

So there are four problems to be solved:

1. How to hook up javascript to the client-side click of the **Delete** link.
2. How to know what item the user clicked **Delete**
3. Prevent a post-back
4. Delete the  row that the user clicked

That is my question.

From here on you will find my rambling attempts to solve it. Don't take anything below as relating in any way to any possible accepted solution. Just because i posted code below, doesn't mean any of it is useful. And it doesn't mean i'm anywhere within spitting distance of the best solution. And because i can't make anything below work - it must have gone down the wrong road.

---

### My Attempts

**Wiring Up Javascript**

The first task is to convert the delete link HTML from something such as:

```
<A href="DeleteItem.aspx?ItemGuid={19a149db-5675-4eee-835d-3d78372ca6f9}">
   Delete
</A>
```

into something more javascripty:

```
<A href="#" 
      onclick="DeleteItem('DeleteItem.aspx?ItemGuid={19a149db-5675-4eee-835d-3d78372ca6f9}')">
   Delete
</A>
```

and the add the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
       function DeleteItem(deleteUrl)   
       {   
          //Ask the user if they really want to
          if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete INSERT NAME HERE?"))
          {
             return false;
          }

          //Call returns false if the server returned anything other than OK
          if (!DoAjaxHit(deleteUrl)
          {
             return false;
          }

          //Remove the table row from the browser
          var tableRow = document.getElementById("TODO-WHAT ID");
          if (row != null)
          {
             //TODO: how to delete the tableRow from the DOM tree?
             //document.Delete(tableRow) ?
          }

          //return false to prevent a postback
          return false;
       }
   //]]>
</script>
```

What combination of ASP code can be used to create the above? i hear that **asp:LinkButton** has an **OnClientClick** event, where you can wire up a javascript function:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkDelete" runat="server"
   Text="Delete"
   OnClientClick="DeleteItem(<%# GetDeleteUrl((ActionItem)Container.DataItem) %>);"/>
```

Problem is that the rendered HTML is literally containing:

```
<a onclick="DeleteItem(&lt;%# GetDeleteUrl((ActionItem)Container.DataItem)) %>);" ...>
   Delete
</a>
```

If i change the client click event handler to:

```
   OnClientClick="DeleteItem('todo - figure this out');"/>
```

it works - as well as "todo - figure this out" can work.

---

**Preventing Postbacks**

The dummied down above javascript call actually happens (i can see my alert), but there's the next problem: Returning false from the javascript function doesn't prevent a postback. In fact, i can see that the *href* on the generated html code isn't "#", but rather

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl0....
```

i tried changing the ASPX code to include the OnClick handler myself:

```
   OnClick="#"
   OnClientClick="DeleteItem('todo - figure this out');"
```

But the compiler thinks the pound side is a pragma, and whines:

> Preprocessor directives must appear as
>   the first non-whitespace character on
>   a line

---

**Table Row Identity**

The table rows don't have an ID, they're generated by the **asp:repeater**.

How can the javascript function know what  triggered the click event? The javascript needs to be able to find the  element, and remove it from the tree.

**Note:** i would of course prefer fade+collapse animation.

Normally you get an element by using

```
var tr = document.getElementById("the table row's id");
```

But the table rows don't have an easily knowable ID. Since there are multiple rows, the server generates the ID as it builds the table. i realize some solution is going to have to involve changing:

```
<TR>
```

into

```
<TR runat="server">
```

so that there will be server generated identity for each table row, but how do i reference the generated name from javsscript?

Normally i would have thought that the scripting problem would be solved by using multiple paramters:

```
function DeleteItem(tableRowElement, deleteUrl)
{
   //Do a web-hit of deleteUrl to delete the item


   //remove tableRowElement DOM object from the document tree
}
```

But the problem is just pushed elsewhere: How do you populate tableRowElement and deleteUrl for the call to the javascript function?

---

Such a simple problem: convert a click from a postback to client-side.

The volume of problems involved is getting quite idiotic. Which seems to indicate that either

- the idea solution is something completely different
- there is no solution

---

### References

[Stackoverflow: How do I fade a row out before postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183179/how-do-i-fade-a-row-out-before-postback)

[Stackoverflow: Javascript before asp:ButtonField click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218733/javascript-before-aspbuttonfield-click)

[asp.net: Accessing repeater elements from javascript.](http://forums.asp.net/p/1116342/1733360.aspx)

[Stackoverflow: How to access repeater generated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480195/asp-net-how-to-access-repeater-generated-elements)

Comment: Six hours of getting nowhere, i can afford to spend an hour authoring a question

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: Depends if it's free and requires no setup besides the assembly dll to the bin folder

Comment: It is free and there is no setup required besides the assembly ddl. It is a great resource that will open a lot of doors from some cool functionality that you may not have thought of before.

Comment: Well i won't be looking at it until this problem is solvable; otherwise i'm just burning hours playing with something that has no practical application.

Comment: jQuery will help you solve your problem. You should look at it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answerers found various bits related to different aspects of the question. i managed to cobble together a complete solution. i've copy/pasted the relavent snippits here.

The first important change is the use of an **asp:LinkButton** which allows as **OnClientClick** event, which gives you direct access to the javascript **OnClick** event:

```
<asp:repeater ID="itemsRepeater"
      OnItemDataBound="itemsRepeater_ItemDataBound"
      runat="Server">
   <itemtemplate>
      <tr>         
         <td>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="linkView" runat="server"
               Text="<%# GetItemText((Item)Container.DataItem) %>"
               NavigateUrl="<%# GetViewItemUrl((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkImpregnate" runat="server"
                   Text="Impregnate"
                   OnClientClick="<%# GetImpregnateUrl((Item)Container.DataItem) %>" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

The code-behind manually builds presentation code (yay for separation of controller and view!) that contains a javascript call.

```
protected string GetNodeAcknowledgementClientClick(Item item)
{
   if (!(item is HotGirl))
      return ""; //this shouldn't be called for non-acknowledgements, but i won't fail

   HotGirl girl = (HotGirl)item;

   String szOnClientClick =
         "return ImpregnateGirl(this, "+
               Toolkit.QuotedStr(girl.GirlGUID.ToString()) + ", "+
               Toolkit.QuotedStr(GetItemName(item))+");";

   return szOnClientClick;
}
```

And finally in the aspx, i find a random spot to mash in some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   function DeleteItem(sender, girlGuid, girlName)   
   {
      if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to impregnate "+girlName+"?"))
      {
         return false;
      }

      $.post(
         'ImpregnateGirl.aspx?GirlGUID='+nodeGuid,
               function(data, textStatus) {
                  if (textStatus == 'success') 
                  {
                     $(sender).parents('tr:eq(0)').hide();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     return false;
                  }
               }
      );

      //return false to suppress the postback
      return false;
   }
//]]>
</script>
```

i would have made the jQuery do a post, as a security measure as guy suggested, but jQuery would give an error, rather than posting. Rather than care i chose to not care.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/) can dig out the  tags for you:

```
$("[id$=linkDelete]").click(function() {
    DeleteItem(this.href);
});
```

That code says "find all the DOM elements whose ID ends with 'linkDelete' and wire up the following click event handler".

Comment: Could you expand on that answer? Where does this code go, how does it go there, and what "this.href" contain?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against implementing the Delete function through links in this way. [Delete links are a security risk.](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/01/21/asp.net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because.aspx)

Rather, it's better to require a post to that url instead. If you want to be doing ajax, I would strongly recommend using a javascript framework so you don't have to deal with the differences in how different browsers implement XmlHttpRequests.

For instance, in jQuery you could do it like this:

```
$.post('Delete.aspx',{itemGuid:'{19a149db-5675-4eee-835d-3d78372ca6f9}'},
    function(data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == 'success') {
            $(this).parents('tr:eq(0)').fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

which would do both the ajax call *and* the fadeout effect you want.

You could then access the item guid in Delete.aspx from Request.Form["itemGuid"], and this wouldn't be vulnerable to link attacks.

**Preventing Postbacks**

The server is generating a postback wireup because you're using a server control. Use a plain `<a>` tag without a runat='server' directive.

**Table Row Identity**

I usually do this by databinding an ID column of some kind and putting this in the repeater template:

```
<tr id='<%#Eval("ID")%>'>
```

P.S. I hate to sound like a fanboy, but jQuery will make all of these things an order of magnitude easier. You should really consider it if you can. Otherwise, you're going to be in a world of hurt trying to implement these features in a consistent way across browsers.

P.P.S. If the Delete.aspx and similar urls are only going to be called from javascript, I would recommend using ashx http handlers instead. You can do all of the same server logic without the needless overhead of a full-blown page.

Comment: i notice the code contains a Guid in it, could you indicate how this code is getting generated, where it goes, and how it gets there?

Comment: I'm just taking that from your code as an example of an id field. To my knowledge, there is currently no way of generating a guid in jQuery. The second field of $.post is a collection of name-value pairs of form variables you want to post to the server.

Answer (score 0):

mine usually comes out looking like

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ID", "DeleteItem(this, \"{0}\"); return false;") %>' Text="Delete" />
```

that will make html that looks like

```
<a id="blah_blah_ctl01" onclick='DeleteItem(this, "{19a149db-5675-4eee-835d-3d78372ca6f9}"); return false;'>Delete</a>
```

I include the "this" reference so that you can have access to the dom and delete the link...or it's parent or whatever.  From there it's pretty straight forward to use jQuery to actually do the posting and DOM manipulation.  The "return false;" disables the postback.